# Custom Form validation in CakePHP

Tags: validation, forms, cakephp

This is my form: I want to make sure that AT LEAST one of the name/email pairs are filled in, so I'm working on a custom validation rule in my model.

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/240752/formfields.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/240752/formfields.png)

I originally thought it would a simple case of making the first name/email pair mandatory, but this doesn't cover the other fields if someone fills in the third one for example, and omits the email.

Also, I only need to check for a valid email address if the corresponding friend field is filled in.

Am I overthinking this? I think I need some kind of interaction between the rules, but I'm stuck hard.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a custom validation method for this purpose: http://book.cakephp.org/view/150/Custom-Validation-Rules#Adding-your-own-Validation-Methods-152

Comment: Hi, dhofstet. I read through that section before posting, but that simply demonstrates how to write a rule for one specific field. I need to 1)Check that a friend is populated 2)If it is check that the corresponding email field is populated & valid.

Comment: Yes, you define a rule for one specific field, however, with $this->data you can access all data from within your validation method. So the field name is just used to trigger the validation method.

Comment: To dhofstet's point, you could create a Custom Validation method to loop through your $this->data['Friend'][]['name'] array and do what's necessary (return false is an email is missing, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

place your validation logic inside beforeValidate callback.

Comment: I can see how that would be called before each validation, but I'm struggling to see how that would help my specific case.

Answer (score 0):

How are your fields being generated?  I assume you're using something like:

```
<?php echo $form->input('Friend.name'); ?> [html stuff] <?php echo $form->input('Friend.email'); ?>
```

Since doing that several times within a page will produce duplicate ids (like, "`FriendName`" would be the resulting ID for each field generated by `<?php echo $form->input('Friend.name'); ?>`), you're probably going to have to add a number to each field name as you're generating them and then loop over `$this->data['Friend']` in your controller and invalidate the offending fields as you find them (if the name is present, but the email is not, as you say).

I don't think there's a built-in way for cake to handle a situation like this, but I've been wrong before!

Comment: Hi inkedmn, heres how I'm generating the fields: http://pastebin.com/m44277054 As you can see they are named data[Friend][0][name]
 etc.